# Finding the location of a character in a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string: `"fdfdfd.dfdfd.dfdfdf.dfdfdf"`.  I want to get the location of the last dot.  I tried this:

```
Index = re.search(r"\w + '.' \w+$", string)
```

but it doesn't work.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `string.rfind()`: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind e.g.

```
"fdfdfd.dfdfd.dfdfdf.dfdfdf".rfind('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I suspect that what you really want is the tail end of the string (whatever comes after the dot). If so, you can do this:

```
tail = re.search(r"\.(\w+)$", string).group(1)
```

Also see @bradley.ayers comment for a simpler answer. I hadn't heard about `rpartition` till now.

Comment: @Don: I've been tweaking my answer. Try the latest.

Comment: `"fdfdfd.dfdfd.dfdfdf.dfdfdf".rpartition('.')[2]` might be better if this is in fact what he's after.

Comment: An easier way to do the same thing: `tail = 'fdfdfd.dfdfd.dfdfdf.dfdfdf'.split('.')[-1]`